# Do all .java files load when the app is opened?

Tags: java, android

I'm just starting into Java/Android apps... I've got a few sample things up and running... but I want to organize my code in a proper manner.  Are all .java files loaded when the app is opened, or do I need to tell it to load other .java files within my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what do you  mean by "loaded"? The .java files are compiled to .dex files when you create your .apk, so no they don't need to be "loaded".

If you're talking about importing in order to use classes in other .java files, then not usually. You only need to use `import` for classes in other packages.

Comment: Right now I have `testWidget.java`, if I create another class on a seperate .java file, do I need to tell testWidget.java to import that class or will I already have access to it?

Comment: So... `com.example.testWidget` is my package?

Comment: import is always optionally it only serves to reduce typing but you can just as well type the fully qualified name whenever you want to use the 2nd class. Personally I prefer fully qualified names — but I am pretty alone with that opinion.

Comment: It sounds like `com.example` is your package. At the top of your java file it should say `package ...`

Comment: @Falmarri: you don't **need** to use import at all. My 30'000 line Android program only has a dozen imports. Class names are not used that often in code and so using fully qualified class names is less painful then most developers think.

Comment: @Martin: Fair enough. I think it's easier to tell people (ie OP) to just import stuff.

Comment: I'd rather learn the most efficient way.  When you say fully qualified names, what do you mean, like including the class name in the call for the function?  Yes, that's my ideal calling method... makes the code more readable in my opinion

Comment: @Webnet: Either of these 2 ways has nothing to do with efficiency. It's 100% personal preference. I think cluttering code with explicit namespaces is less readable (fully qualified names are usually 3-4+ dotted sections in java). If everything is in your package, you don't have to import anything or qualify anything.

Comment: @Falmarri: As you say: personal preference: I think fully qualified names make the code more readable. It is helpful to know if a class comes from `javax.ejb` or `javax.jms`. And you don't need to repeat parts of the package name in the class name as in: `java.io.IOException`. If that was my class it would be: `java.io.Exception` ;-) - why have two IOs in the name? Even better are the import rules from Scala where you could `import java.io` and then use `io.Exception`.

Comment: So if I had 2 files, 1 was `ContactWidget.java` and the other was `ContactLib.java`, within `ContactWidget.java` I needed to use the `listContacts()` function in the lib file, you're saying a fully qualified name would be something like.... `ContactLib.listContacts()`?

Answer (score 1):

There won't bee any .java files in your Android application.

The .java files will be compiled to .class files which in turn will be compiled into a **single** .dex file which then will be added to the .apx file.

Sounds complicated but the build system will take care of it all. And since there is only one .dex file the whole application is loaded in one piece.

Comment: It doesn't sound like Variable scope is going to be much of an issue... so I can have as many .java files as I want.... nice

Comment: You HAVE to have many java files. Public classes HAVE to be in their own java file, so you really have no choice anyway.

Comment: @Falmarri: That is only a minimum requirement for a compliant Java compiler. It is not forbidden for a compliant Java compiler to support multiple public classes in one file. Mind you, I don't know any actual compiler which does.

Comment: Can you point to the spec where that is specified (or not as the case may be)? I'm not a java expert, but I always thought that was a requirement of java.

Comment: I learned it in the preparation course for the SCJP (where you learn a lot of corner cases). Compilers are free to accept the souce as they chosse — for example in a database as eclipse (and before that Visual Age for Java) does — as long as an export/conversion tool is provided that export/converts the code in a form that an minimum requirement compiler can compile it.